# How add custom config to my Yii extensions

Tags: configuration, yii, yii-extensions

I'm trying to build a custom extension in Yii, but having trouble accessing the custom configuration.

Suppose I have the following in main.php:

```
'my_extension'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.my_extension.my_extension'
    'custom_config'=>array(
        'first_option'=>array(
            'active'=>true,
            'custom_username'=>'username',
            'custom_password'=>'password',
        ),
    ),
),
```

How do I get access to 'active', 'custom_username' and 'custom_password'?

In my extension, which extends CFormModel, I tried:

```
Yii::app()->my_extension->custom_config['first_option']['custom_username'];
```

But I get the error:

```
Property "my_extension.custom_config" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the reason this is erroring is because you are trying to access a property of Yii::app(), which is not declared, defined in a array..

The entry script (index.php) typically creates the Yii object like this..

```
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

the $config variable is your main.config file array, so even if you add a index in array, which doesn't match in the properties of Yii::app(), it won't create that..

To do set custom configs, Yii provides us `params`..which can be used as `Yii::app()->params['paramName']`

so in you case it'll be, in the end of config.main the 'params' index will be like..

```
'params'=>array(
    'my_extension'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.my_extension.my_extension',
        'custom_config'=>array(
            'first_option'=>array(
                'active'=>true,
                'custom_username'=>'username',
                'custom_password'=>'password',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    //...remaining params
),
```

and the usage will be

```
Yii::app()->params['my_extension']['custom_config']['first_option']['custom_username'];
```

**Edit:**

There are cases when u need to configs of yr extension, or some thing like facebook or postmark separately, maybe because of having separate values in separate environments, and want to put that file in `.gitignore`, or maybe because you want to release yr extension to open-source, and want people to give clear way of having its own config..

So in those cases, the solution is make a file in yr ext, or anywhere, make a array in that which contains the config values, include that file in `index.php`, and in yr `config/main`,
put that content..

In your case:

```
//in index.php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/ext/yr_ext/ext_config.php');

//in ext/yr_ext/ext_config.php
<?php
class ExtConfiguration {
public static function fetchConfigArray() {
        return array(
        'class'=>'ext.my_extension.my_extension',
                'custom_config'=>array(
                    'first_option'=>array(
                        'active'=>true,
                        'custom_username'=>'username',
                        'custom_password'=>'password',
                    ),
                ),
            );
    }
}
?>

//in config/main.php
//on top before array start
$ext_config = ExtConfiguration::fetchConfigArray();

//in params
'params'=>array(
    'my_extension'=>$ext_config,
),
//...remaining params
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! So, is it the "Yii way" to include ALL custom config (modules/extensions) in params (within main.php)?  Or do you store the config per extension/module within the module/extension?

Answer (score 1):

By the config fragment you shared us, you mentioned you must define in your main class the public property `$custom_config`.

And simply you use like in your extension like `$this->custom_config`

Comment: I added `public $custom_config;` to my extension class, but the value is empty, how can I get the array custom_config from main.php (with custom_username, custom_password, etc)